# Registering SignalR - Reference issue?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, signalr

I am following this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#groupsfromhub

Having trouble with the first task "How to register SignalR middleware"

In a file called OwinStartup.vb I have...

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Owin

<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(MyApplication.Startup))> 

Namespace MyApplication
    Public Class Startup
        Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
            ' Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR()
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

VS 2013 does not like this line: app.MapSignalR() It is telling me: 'MapSignalR' is not a member of 'Owin.IAppBuilder'

I think I have all the required references added. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not add a Hub as a first thing, and go straight to the Startup class, I think you'll miss some references. The Extension method you are missing is from Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, make sure it's referenced and try again. Or add a Hub to your project, that will bring down the references you need.

Comment: So I tried what you suggested, still didn't work.
So I created a new project from scratch and imported everything from the old one and now it seems to work.